# I am trying to add authentication to my application, and I am getting the following mapping error when doing so:

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, authentication

I am currently coding the authentication for my application from a code that was already working. But firebase_auth had a recent update which changed a lot of the function/method names.

Error: The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'.

```
abstract class BaseAuth {
  Stream<String> get authStateChanges;
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email,
    String password,
  );
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email,
    String password,
  );

  Future<String> currentUser();
  Future<void> signOut();
  Future<String> signInWithGoogle();
}

class Auth implements BaseAuth {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();


  Stream<String> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges.map(
        (User user) => user?.uid,
      );
```

If anybody has a potential solution it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Please try to explain your code more.

Comment: So the code is in a file called auth.dart where I am trying to setup up email/password and google sign in for my application using the firebase_auth package. I am using code from the flutter documentation but it is not up to date with the firebase_auth package. I will add more code to my query for context.

Comment: So you are using firebase auth for sign-in/creating users and it gives you an error when you check if the user is still logged in?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `_firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {});`?

Comment: Unfortunately that still throws an error @PeterKoltai. The error reads: A value of type 'StreamSubscription<User?>' can't be returned from the function 'authStateChanges' because it has a return type of 'Stream<String>'.

Comment: @LloydWingrove If you do like `final authStateChanges = _firebaseAuth...` it should be working. This is a stream subscription, and not a `Stream<String>`, that's what the error is about.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Thank you so much, I got the code working. Did map get removed from firebase auth in one of the updates as it was working in older code.

Comment: @LloydWingrove You are welcome. As far as I know you can use `map` on the stream, but not on the stream subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you how I solved the process of login/register and login check with firebase and flutter.

For login I used the following method:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                   email: emailController.text,
                   password: passwordController.text);
```

For Register:

```
 await FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                              email: emailController.text,
                              password: passwordController.text);
```

And to check if the user is currently logged in you can use:

```
if(User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.CurrentUser != null){}
```

I hope that helps you somehow